# Why can't I build this code in Sublime text 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, sublimetext2

I need to build a schedule so I found an example (see In [13], Out [13])

[http://playittodeath.ru/анализ-данных-при-помощи-python-графики-в-pandas/](http://playittodeath.ru/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-python-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-pandas/)

However, when I copy it into Sublime Text 2 I get this output:

```
sh: sysctl: command not found
sh: grep: command not found
sh: sw_vers: command not found
sh: grep: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

I use MacOS and Python 2.7.

Comment: Might be a one time thing after it builds the font list... did you try running it again?

Comment: Yes I tried it several times.

Comment: Your error message does not match up with your input.

Comment: I did not say that it is an error massage. I sad it is my output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it worked when i modified my Sublime build file. Here is original:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

And here is modified one:

```
{
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/",
    "cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

For getting path you need you should run `which python` in your terminal and copy it in "path". And then you should run `open *your path*` in your terminal and find pyhon.exe or it can by a python python*version*.exe and put it's name in "cmd".

Comment: Doing this alone will not solve the problem you described in the question.